# GNSS : Code Phase and Carrier Phase Relation

Tags: spread-spectrum, gps, gnss

What is the relation between code phase and carrier phase in a GNSS system (GPS L1CA, GPS L5 etc)? Any document or section of any book explaining the same will also do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the only relation is that they're both caused by the distance between transmitter and receiver (and delays, phase shifts).

"Code phase" applies the idea of *phase* (which is typically a property of a harmonic oscillation relative to some other reference oscillation of the same freqeuncy) to the code sequence of GNSS systems. Instead of asking "how much of the $2\pi$ of a full period of the oscillation are we shifted?" you'd be asking "how much of the full length of a code sequence are we shifted?". You'd learn that by cross-correlating receive signal with the known PRN, and getting a position between 0 shift and sequence length (e.g. 1023); that position doesn't have to be an integer, though, as you're free to interpolate in your receiver if SNR permits.

Hence, code phase is the result of range modulo (code sequence length)/$c_0$.

Carrier phase is just that – the phase of your carrier at the receiver. Look at the correlation peak above: it's a complex number, it not only got a magnitude, but also a phase.

Galileo publishes information on the phase centers of their satellite antennas – so, if your GNSS pseudorange estimation (based on the estimate of pseudoranges made up of full multiples of sequence lengths, and the code phase) is good enough, you can further increase it by observing the carrier phase as recovered from your correlation-based estimate.